# Porting a game developed in Qt (for KDE) to Android

Tags: android, qt, qml

I have game (of cards based on [Contract Bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contract_bridge)) written in Qt (QML) for KDE, now I'm supposed to port the entire game to Android (with Android apapted UI of course). At first I considered to use [Necessitas](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/02/28/necessitas/) (a Qt port for Android) but found that it is still under development and is currently in 3rd Alpha. I'm new to Android development (as well as game development), while I have experience working in Java, C++ and web technologies like HTML5, JavaScript.

Hence based on my skills, I considered using [MoSync](http://www.mosync.com/). But I'm not sure if I'll be able to use any existing modules of game already developed in Qt (while in MoSync its possible to invoke C++ code from JavaScript and vice-versa), and since I didn't worked on the Qt version of the game, I'll first have to refer to that code and then I'll be working on Android version of the same. So I need suggestion that from where should I start. Also, I have 1.5 months of duration to complete the project (without any working hour constraints), so also suggest me if its a good idea to work from scratch using Android APIs.

Please let me know if I need to elaborate the question even further.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I am interested too, as I am in a similar situation. I am supposed to port a QT-software to Android, and the only thing I've found is Necessitas. As you said it is an alpha software. The developer himself doesn't recommend to upload any app developed with it on the play store yet. I really don't know if it is worth it though. Even if I can make the software run, it will never be fully integrated within the system. I mean how would Life cycle be handled, or interaction with android framework components (keyboard, etc..), and also would it run on screen with different resolutions? help! :)

Comment: @Danny: MoSync looks quite promising as far as platform integration is concerned, but in my case, the game is written in QML rather than C++, and hence I doubt if MoSync is able to work with that, while using C++ code within JavaScript under MoSync is possible, and MoSync is also fairly stable to work on any serious/commercial project where there's high possibility to port an app across multiple mobile platforms.

Comment: but I am afraid you need to port your app/game to MoSync actually (whatever that means), and then let it port it for you to one of the supported platforms you need. I think a software should be first designed with that in mind (the fact that it will be ported) otherwise might result in a poor software experience once ported. For a game in your case, could still be ok, as the user will keep the main focus on the app while it is open (nobody starts browsing the web while playing a game),might be different for a multimedia application... so maybe a game would require less integration with android

Comment: @Danny: Yes game will be having its own UI, while native dialogs only appear for general things life, preferences, options, etc. hence native integration is not an issue here. Also, the game is all 2D graphics (thus can be developed plainly in MoSync HTML5/JS APIs) and hence doesn't need special hardware capabilities of device to be used.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend taking a look at [V-Play](http://v-play.net/) (v-play.net). It's a cross platform game engine based on Qt/QML .
If your game is already written in QML, you have the least porting effort because you can use almost all of your existing code, and use V-Play QML game components for handling multiple display resolutions & aspect ratios, animations, particles, physics, multi-touch, gestures, path finding and more ([API reference](http://v-play.net/doc/vplay-group.html)).

You can also take a look at [Benefits](http://v-play.net/benefits/#qtdeveloper) to find out if V-Play satisfies your demands.

Comment: It is quote old question, thanks for taking time and providing a possible solution. However, my game wasn't very graphics intensive and hence I ended up creating it using core Android APIs (thus rewriting entire game).

Answer (score 0):

Qt is more cross-platform than ever now. instead of porting, just modify it a little and continue with Qt, then compile for iOS, Android, etc.